# Function that interpretes trailing 'n' characters of a word as argument

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

Is there a way to pass the trailing *n* characters of a command to a function, so that it executes it as two commands? For example I define my function as abcx and whenever I enter

```
abcxfoo
```

to the command line, my function interpretes it as `abcx foo`. I am aware of passing arguments such as `$1` and `$@` but in some cases a once defined function as that one above could really be a timesaver.

What I'm referring to is, I have a lot of `cd` aliases which I'd like to call like `cdlinux`, making me change to *~/Documents/Linux*, without the need of defining an alias for every single folder inside my *Documents* (which is what I've done so far to the date).

Comment: `for d in ~/Documents/*/; do alias cd$(basename  "$d")="cd $d" ;done` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't exactly do that, but with a bit of work and bash 4, you can implement the feature.

When bash 4 encounters an undefined command, it looks for a shell function called `command_not_found_handle` and if it finds it, it calls it, passing the unfound command name as `$1` and the remaining arguments as `$2`...

So you could, for example, handle your `cd` and `ffdir` commands by adding something like this to your `.bashrc` file. (note: I don't deal with case-insensitivity here, so there's still some work to do.)

```
command_not_found_handle() {
  case $1 in
    cd*) if [[ -d "$HOME/Documents/${1#cd}" ]]; then
           cd "$HOME/Documents/${1#cd}"
           return 0
         fi
         # On failure, falls through to the error message
         ;;
    ffdir*) find . -type d -iname "${1#ffdir}"
            return 0
            ;;
    # Etc...
  esac

  # If nothing else works, just do what bash would have done
  printf "%s: command not found\n" "$1" >&2
  return 127
}
```

Comment: +1 for the effort, but is it really worth it? I mean, a parameter not separated by spaces from its command? How much weirder does it get?

Comment: couldn't have asked for more, this is just... perfect! thank you @rici

Comment: Nice, now i just need that for zsh... :)

Comment: @sjas: In zsh, the function is called `command_not_found_handler`. It works the same way.

Answer (score 0):

No. What you're asking for is impossible, how could the shell be able to guess where the function name ends? It needs a space to know that it should attempt to interpret what you wrote as a command.

However, what you're looking for is probably the [`CDPATH`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Variables.html#Bourne-Shell-Variables) environment variable:

> CDPATH
>
> A colon-separated list of directories used as a search path for the cd builtin command.

This is used by `cd` as follows:

> cd
>
> ```
>   cd [-L|[-P [-e]]] [directory]
> ```
>
> Change the current working directory to directory. If directory is not given, the value of the HOME shell variable is used. **If the shell variable CDPATH exists, it is used as a search path.** If directory begins with a slash, CDPATH is not used.

In other words, if you set `CDPATH` in your `~/.bashrc` like this:

```
export CDPATH=".:~/Documents"
```

You will then be able to `cd` and use tab completion to list all subdirectories of `~/Documents` as though you were already within `~/Documents`.

---

Another approach would be to use a function. Just add this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
cddoc(){
    cd "$HOME/Documents/$1"
}
```

This, however, has the drawback that tab completion will not work. You can get around that but it's not worth it given that `CDPATH` is probably exactly what you're after.

Comment: thanks, that pretty much makes life easyier for changing directories. Didn't know adding a folder to your $PATH would make tab-completion work. Anyways I've put `cdlinux` to my question to add some practical relevance. For example I have another alias which is `ffdir=find . -type d -iname` and I would like to trigger it as so: `ffdirlinux` to make it find the directory **Linux** in all subdirectories. Most of them are related to **git** aliases, which I call the most.

Comment: @emzap79 no, that's not possible. As I said, the shell only starts interpreting a command when it gets to the first space. It has no way of knowing that `ffdir` is a function or an alias and so it should treat the rest of the word as an argument. But that's what functions are for: `ffdir() { find . -type d iname "$1"; }`. That will let you run `ffdir Linux` and find any directories called `Linux`. For something this simple though, you can use the exact alias you have. Just run `ffdir Linux` instead of trying `ffdirLinux` that will also work.